# how to post data to two php pages simultaneously & parallely execute them?

Tags: php, post

I want to parallelly post the data to two pages that operates on data independently. So that no time wastage occur. I can execute them serially but want to post data to both pages simultaneously and execute parallelly. Please suggest me any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send two ajax request using javascript.

Using jQuery it will be something like

```
$.post('first_page.php', {data: 'Some Data'}, function(response) {
   // process 1st page
});
$.post('second_page.php', {data: 'Some Data'}, function(response) {
   // process 2nd page
});
```